# Enumeration definition in XML Schema is redundant

Tags: xml, xsd

Please just confirm (or refute) that this enumeration within a schema definition (.xsd file) is redundant (due to the second simpleType just letting through anything being 5 characters long or less):

```
<simpleType name="decision">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>It will decide the flow</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <union>
        <simpleType>
            <restriction base="string">
                <enumeration value="yes"/>
                <enumeration value="no"/>
                <enumeration value="maybe"/>
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
        <simpleType>
            <restriction base="string">
                <maxLength value="5"/>
            </retriction>
        </simpleType>
    </union>
<simpleType>
```

We've got quite a few of these things all over our application, so we should optimize it.

Comment: Even if there is no *technical* advantage of having that union, it's *at least* documentation that the three values (`yes`, `no` and `maybe`) have a special meaning.

Comment: aside from the 3 values being a "documentation" about what's expected ... is it doing anything for real or it's just letting any string of 5 characters or less through? ..that was the question

Answer (score 1):

What you see is rather a pattern used by XSD authors to provide forward/backward compatibility for what I call "extensible enumerations".

For some this is an oxymoron. To me it means that one has to prepare its implementation of this contract to **gracefully** handle values other than the listed ones.

The contract designer decided that for those particular types, there should be no "fail fast" rejection (typically done by an XSD validator) simply because some of the consumers may not have business logic around the enumerated values, while **others may**.

Of course, it ultimately seems do be a "confusing" way to documentation... Imagine though that an XSD to code implementation such as .NET's xsd.exe, svcutil.exe or Java JAXB's would be so smart (they're not) as to still create an enum type, having `yes`, `no`, `maybe`, and **other** with the latter being a catch all for all other values. I wonder if, assuming the above, you'll still see this as redundant? Code coverage pundits would love it...

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant if you are only using the schema for validation.

If you are using the schema for data binding, or for schema-aware XSLT/XQuery processing, or for documentation, or for generating instances, or for generating forms, then this kind of design can sometimes be useful. It can also sometimes make your schema more extensible / customizable. (But these are general points about unions, I'm not sure your specific case is useful.)